# simple javascript search() function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, split

I am trying to find some string part in another string. And I found a function called `search()` and tried this:

```
if("http://www.google.de".search("http://") > 0){
  alert('with http');    
} else {
  alert('no http');   
}
```

but it is giving me `no http` even if it has `http://` part in it. here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xXTuY/2/

can you please help me out?

Comment: try reversing the condition

Comment: `search` expects a regex, not a literal match

Comment: I've reverted `~` back to `> -1` in my answer. Was that why you've unaccepted?

Comment: Please unaccept Chris' answer. He wants to delete it as it is incorrect.

Comment: @doniyor out of interest where are you getting the string `http://www.google.de` from?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray, from user input.

Comment: @JanDvorak, thanks, i changed the answer to yours. you are right

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, [`String#search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) expects a regex, not a string. If it encounters a non-regex, it tries to convert it into a regex via `new RegExp(patt)`. In case of a string, it treats the string as a regex pattern. This means that your search will behave unexpectedly (match more than desired, match less than desired or even throw a syntax error, if the string is not a valid regex) if the search string contains characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions. Use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) instead.

Second, `search` and `indexOf` return the position of the first match, or -1 if no match has been found. This means that if the return value is less than zero, nothing has been found. If the return value is zero, the match was made at the beginning of the string.

Also note there is a handy shortcut for `x != -1`: the bitwise negation `~x`

```
if("http://www.google.de".indexOf("http://") > -1){
  alert('with http');    
} else {
  alert('no http');   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`"http://www.google.de".search("http://")` returns 0. 0 is not less than 0 so your condition evaluates to false.

Comment: works as expected, I used `search` and it broke my code when a user types \
`indexOf` fixes this bug and it produces the same return value as `search`